# Get the record details and calculate the ranking

Tags: mysql

I have a table of exam results. I need to get the record of a specific participant and get his/her ranking too.

[image]

for example, the participant with the participant_id 15 must have the ranking 3 amongst the total 4 records. so the result i am looking for would be:

```
id: 1
exam_id: 3
participant_id: 15
score: 343.23
ranking: 3
```

I know I can get the record and get the ranking through some PHP code, but I wonder if this is possible with Mysql queries.

I googled but did not really come up with a good solution. Any answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with PHP? And how does ranking work with ties?

Answer (score 1):

This is the row_number function in postgresql and other databases which unfortunately isn't present in mysql.

This article http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ explains how to emulate it in mysql

To adapt the example from it

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, id, participant_id,exam_id, score 
FROM
    exams
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the required result

```
select t2.id,t2.exam_id,t2.exam_id,t2.participant_id,t2.score,t2.ranking from
(SELECT t.id,t.exam_id,t.participant_id,t.score,(@num:=@num+1) AS
 ranking  FROM table1 t cross join (SELECT @num:=0) AS dummy 
 ORDER BY t.score desc)as t2 where t2.participant_id=15;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query to create a separate table of results and then add condition to get the rank of required participant.

here is the query you can try

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT re.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS rank
FROM results re JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE 1 ORDER BY re.`score` DESC) AS tablea
WHERE participant_id=15
```

here is the result

```
id exam_id participant_id score  rank
1  3       15             343.23 3
```